# What is mean MPP Databases, and are Oracle and SQL Server one of these databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, teradata

We work to study database types.We found one of types is MPP databases. What is mean MPP Databases?, and  are Oracle and SQL Server one of these databases, specifically we can create data warehouse schema ,if the MPP databases are data warehouse ?

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Look this: http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/MPP-database-massively-parallel-processing-database

Answer (score 3):

In this context, I believe that MPP standard for "massive parallel processing".

When this term was invented, it referred to any database (or software architecture) that was scalable in hardware.  This includes the ability to increase the number of the disks and processors arbitrarily -- although restructuring the data might be necessary.

Originally, databases such as Oracle, Teradata, Tandem, and DB2 were examples of MPP databases.  SQL Server now has a scalable architecture, so I would put it in this category as well.

I do think that newer technologies, such as Google BigQuery are more scalable than even these products (although that might be verging on opinion).